# Cython incorrectly skips recompile when modifying an include

Tags: include, cython, setup.py

I have a cython file `combined.pyx`, which merges several pyx files together:

```
include file1.part.pyx
include file2.part.pyx
...
```

I also have a setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext, Extension

setup(
    ext_modules=[Extension(
        "bla.combined",
        ["src/bla/combined.pyx"])],
    requires=['Cython'],
    cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext})
```

Which I run like this:

```
python setup.py build_ext --build-lib src
```

The problem I'm running into is that the setup only looks at `combined.pyx` when determining whether or not it needs to run again. It doesn't pay attention to `file1.part.pyx`, so when I modify `file1.part.pyx` and re-run the setup nothing happens:

```
 python2.7 setup.py build_ext --build-lib src
 running build_ext
 skipping 'src/bla/combined.c' Cython extension (up-to-date)

 Process finished with exit code 0
```

How do I tell cython/python that it needs to also check `file1.part.pyx` and `file2.part.pyx` when determining whether to recompile `combined.pyx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to `cythonize` the extension before giving it to `setup`.

A fixed `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Distutils import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(
        "bla.combined",
        ["src/bla/combined.pyx"])),
    requires=['Cython'])
```